# Is the second comma needed in this sentence?

Tags: punctuation, commas

> (1) Therefore, in order to achieve maximum power, the source must be able to burn within the correct range.

> (2) Therefore, in order to achieve maximum power the source must be able to burn within the correct range.

Is the comma needed between "power" and "the"?

Comment: Either ***include both*** commas (optionally delineating the "parenthetical" adverbial element, the presence of which is itself optional), or ***remove both*** (they're supposed to be used as a "matched pair").

Comment: Note that initial ***therefore*** can *itself* be classed as an optional parenthetical element. But if we *remove* it, there's still a stylistic choice as to whether to include a comma after the *remaining* parenthetical "adverb of purpose" element ***in order to achieve maximum power***.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, taking in consideration that after the comma you are giving a solution. I think both are Not incorrect but, option (a) gives more clarity and separation in the sentence.

Another reason is that in this case, you started with the consequence.
e.g.
Therefore, the source must be able to burn within the correct range to achieve maximum power.
In this case, I see indeed no reason for a comma.

Comment: @hannah if I answered your question, it would be much appreciated if you click the check ✔ button under my answer to mark it.

Thank you.